# VMediaPlayer don't show video on ios 11

Tags: ios, media-player, vitamio

I have a problem with player on IOS. I use VMediaPlayer (Vitamio) to play mp4 file and HLS stream. 
On ios 10 and lower works fine, but in ios 11 I haven't video, only sound.

This is my code:

```
    if (!mMPlayer) {
    mMPlayer = [VMediaPlayer sharedInstance];
    [mMPlayer setupPlayerWithCarrierView:self.videoCanvas withDelegate:self];
    [mMPlayer setBufferSize:512*1024];
    [mMPlayer setVideoQuality:VMVideoQualityHigh];
    [mMPlayer setVolume:1.0f];
}
NSURL *videoURL = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: self.videoURL ];
[mMPlayer setDataSource:videoURL header:nil];
NSArray *key = @[@"-rtmp_live"];
NSArray *val = @[@"-1"];
[mMPlayer setOptionsWithKeys:key withValues:val];
[mMPlayer prepareAsync];
[player start];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on GitHub about your exact problem:

https://github.com/yixia/Vitamio-iOS/issues/58

and no solution so far, one user suggesting switch to another player like `ijkplayer`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this workaround.

```
mMPlayer.setVideoShown(false)

mMPlayer.setVideoShown(true)
```